# Proto space invaders (can you blit it?)

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, animation

**Proto space invaders**

This is a graphical output challenge where the task is to give the shortest code per language.

**Task**

Your code should allow the user to move the following alien around the screen/window.

[image]

Your code can simply load it from a local file.  Feel free to convert it to another standard image format or even to fix the small pixel errors in the image that were pointed out in the comments.

The background should be white and the window/screen must be at least 400 pixels by 400 pixels.  If your language doesn't support windows/screens that large then use the largest size it does support as long as that is not less than 200 by 200.

To move the alien around the screen the code should support up/down/left/right using the arrows keys on a standard keyboard.

Your code should be a **full program**.

**Restrictions/constraints**

The alien should stop at the borders.  It should also move at a uniform rate **smoothly** with no visible flickering or stuttering and be shown at at least 24fps. It should take between 2 and 5 seconds to go from one side of the screen/window to the other.

**Languages and libraries**

You can use any language or library you like (that wasn't designed for this challenge). However, I would like to be able to test your code if possible so if you can provide clear instructions for how to run it in Ubuntu that would be very much appreciated.

#### Catalog

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = 62426; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 9206; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: Can we construct the alien ourselves? If so, do we have to include the pixel errors (i guess?) from the picture?

Comment: @mınxomaτ It isn't limited to linux! Note "if possible".

Comment: @nimi Thanks. Added that you can load it from a local file.

Comment: @mınxomaτ You can construct it yourself or just load it  from a local file.  I hadn't noticed the pixel errors but I assume that loading it will be less code in any case.

Comment: Can you define "stop at the borders"? Does the entire alien need to be visible at all times, or can it stop partially outside the border?

Comment: The whole alien should be visible at all times.

Comment: @timothymh I am not sure I understand the question but I think the answer is no. The alien should move as in the python solution below, if that helps.  That is it should move while a key is pressed and stop as soon as it is released.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I am afraid the answer is no. I have been told I need to be strict with my rules. 24fps is the minimum.

Comment: Can it be ASCII art if I choose a programming language without a platform-independent graphical API?

Comment: @PeterLenkefi No! :)  That's a different challenge.

Comment: Is it acceptable to convert the image to a different format (such as GIF)?

Comment: @Moose Yes it is. You can even fix the small pixels errors that were pointed out in the image.

Answer (score 12):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/about/), <s>221</s> 217 bytes

[image]

Click the image to view it in action. The movement is determined by *keystrokes*, so it will be smoother the faster your key repeat is set.

The image is included within the project, but Scratch bytes are usually counted from the golfed [textual representation](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%5Bup%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20y%20by(9%0Awhen%5Bleft%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20x%20by(-9%0Awhen%5Bany%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Aif%20on%20edge%20bounce%0Awhen%5Bdown%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20y%20by(-9%0Awhen%5Bright%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20x%20by(9), per [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/673/golfing-from-scratch/5013#5013). If there is disagreement as to whether this is acceptable (or whether the movement is smooth enough) let me know and I will try to work around it.

Comment: This answer is a lot of fun!

Comment: How did you measure the size of this program?

Comment: @Lembik see the second paragraph.

Comment: generates in 217 bytes: http://scratchblocks.github.io/#when%5Bup%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20y%20by(9%0Awhen%5Bleft%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20x%20by(-9%0Awhen%5Bany%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Aif%20on%20edge%20bounce%0Awhen%5Bdown%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20y%20by(-9%0Awhen%5Bright%20arrow%20v%5Dkey%20pressed%0Achange%20x%20by(9

Comment: @ev3commander Good catch, thanks — I accidentally pasted the wrong version!

Comment: Does the alien stop at the borders of the window?

Comment: @Mauris Yes, that's what the "if on edge, bounce" command takes care of. You can play the demo by clicking on the image!

Comment: Ah, I see. ^^ Scratch appears to be down for maintenance, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Ah, I just posted a Scratch A to another Q. I had no idea how to count, I'll have to fix that

Answer (score 6):

### Processing 2, <s>219 199 241 220</s> 219 bytes

```
int a,x=0,y=0;void setup(){size(500,500);}void draw(){background(-1);image(loadImage(".png"),x,y);if(keyPressed){a=keyCode;if(a==38)y--;if(a==37)x--;if(a==40)y++;if(a==39)x++;}x=constrain(x,0,436);y=constrain(y,0,454);}
```

Requires the image saved as `.png` in the same directory as the .pde

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, <s>262</s> <s>253</s> <s>246</s> 240 bytes

```
from pygame import*
init()
key.set_repeat(1)
p=[0,0]
d=display
c=d.set_mode((400,)*2)
while c.fill((255,)*3):
 e=event.get(2);c.blit(image.load("I"),p);d.flip()
 if e:x=e[0].key+1;q=x&2;b=q/2;p[b]=max(0,min(336+b*16,p[b]+(1-q)*(1-(2*x&2))))
```

Wow. What a lot of hackery.

Uses the module 'pygame' found at http://pygame.org.

#### Explanation

`key.set_repeat(1)` - Send repeat key events through the event system every millisecond

`c=d.set_mode((400,)*2)` - Create the 400x400 display surface

`while c.fill((255,)*3):` - Effectively `while 1:` but clears the screen as well

`e=event.get(2);c.blit(image.load("I"),p);d.flip()` - Only collect keyboard events, load the image stored in a png file called `I` and draw it. Update the screen

`if e:x=e[0].key+1;q=x&2;b=q/2;p[b]=max(0,min(336+b*16,p[b]+(1-q)*(1-(2*x&2))))` - If there was an event, work out which arrow key was pressed (does weird stuff if you press other keys), and then change the position of the surface depending on which key you pressed.

Comment: I really like your solution.

Comment: @Lembik So a single byte file name is allowed? (I.e. without extension?). If so, I suggest to exclude filenames completely from the byte count.

Comment: @mınxomaτ I single byte file name is allowed but I don't want to invent a new scoring scheme.

Comment: @Lembik Processing can't handle single-byte filenames... so this is unfair.

Comment: @TheDoctor This just in: Different languages are different! I propose we also disallow challenges that take input from stdin, you know, because it's unfair that it takes so many characters to do that in Python...

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 410 bytes

```
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.Pure.Game
main=do b<-loadBMP"b";play(InWindow""(400,400)(0,0))white 200((0,0),id)(b#)e(%)
e(EventKey(SpecialKey k)Down _ _)(c,_)|k==KeyUp=(c,fmap(+1))|k==KeyDown=(c,fmap(+(-1)))|k==KeyLeft=(c,((+(-1))?))|k==KeyRight=(c,((+1)?))
e(EventKey _ Up _ _)(c,_)=(c,id)
e _ w=w
_%(c,f)=(s?(s<$>f c),f)
s=min 200.max(-200)
b#((x,y),_)=Translate x y b
f?(a,b)=(f a,b)
```

The picture of the alien is expected in a file named `b` in `.bmp` format.

I'm new to the Gloss library, so maybe this is not optimal. Does anyone know if I can check if a key is pressed instead of tracking `KeyUp`/`KeyDown` events?

How it works: the last four parameters of `play` are the world state (initialized with `((0,0),id)`, a function to draw a picture from a state (`#`), an event handler (`e`) and a function that changes the state over time (`%`).

The state is a pair of x-y-coordinates and a function how to change them whenever `%` is called.

`#` moves the bitmap (`b`) to the current coordinates and draw it.

`e` looks for either `KeyDown` events of the cursor keys and sets appropriate functions in the state or for `KeyUp` of any key to reset the function in the state to the identity function.

`%` applies the function from the state to the current coordinates and checks the boundaries.

Comment: I am always amazed you can even do this sort of thing in Haskell. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## Elm, 240 bytes

```
import Graphics.Element as G
import Keyboard as K
import Time
import Signal exposing(..)
c=min 800>>max 64
i(x,y)=G.container x y G.middle(G.image 64 48"https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUweU.png")
main=i<~foldp(\{x,y}(v,w)->(c v+x,c w-y))(99,99)(sampleOn(Time.fps 200)K.arrows)
```

[Try it here](http://elm-lang.org/try). Byte count is after replacing the URL with `.png`.

Comment: I might have to learn Elm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), <s>269</s> 267 bytes

```
#include<Misc.au3>
GUICreate(0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,34078728)
$0=GUICtrlCreatePic("b.bmp",0,0,64,48)
GUISetState()
Dim $1,$2
$3=_IsPressed
Do
$1+=$3("27")-$3("25")
$2+=$3("28")-$3("26")
$1=($1>336)?336:($1<0)?0:$1
$2=($2>352)?352:($2<0)?0:$2
GUICtrlSetPos($0,$1,$2)
Until 0
```

Requires the picture to be saved as b.bmp in the script directory. If you want to use a picture with actual transparency, you have to to convert it from PNG to a 32bit Bitmap (OT: a really unappreciated format).

#### Explanation

We need to import `Misc.au3` to get access to [`_IsPressed`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IsPressed.htm). A function that accepts a key code and returns `True` or `False` when the key is pressed.

The spec of the challenge is quite cool in the way that we have to create a 400px square window. The default (denoted as `-1` or `Default`) size parameters are 400x400. The [extended windows style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) is set to `34078728`. This forces the window to be double-buffered and drawn from bottom to top. This is necessary to eliminate flickering as per the challenge requirement. In Windows 10, this unusual (and somewhat undocumented) combination of styles breaks the window title bar (all hovering effects are disabled).

`$1` and `$2` are declared and will hold the x and y offset of the picture loaded by the control `$0`. `$3` becomes a pointer to the function `_IsPressed` to shorten the code significantly.

Since it is not required to be able to exit the program, this script runs in an infinite loop (`Until 0`).

`$1+=$3("27")-$3("25")` abuses the variant datatype in AutoIt by dynamically casting the boolean value returned from `_IsPressed` to an integer that can be added or sub'ed from the x offset. Same for y. `$1=($1>336)?336:($1<0)?0:$1` uses the ternary operator known from C-like languages to perform a bounds check to stop the alien at the borders.

[`GuiCtrlSetPos`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetPos.htm) moves the picture control to the new coordinates.

Here's a screenshot with a transparent alien (you can even move diagonally):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your background is not white!

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - <s>285</s> 255 bytes

```
1 GRAPHIC NEW v LOAD "inv8.bmp" TRANSPARENT 15
2 PALETTE COPY v,0,1 TO 5: GRAPHIC REMAP v
3 LET x,y=100
4 CLS : WINDOW PUT GRAPHIC v,0,x,y
5 LET x=x+KEYST(39)-KEYST(37),y=y+KEYST(40)-KEYST(38)
6 LET x=CLAMP(x,1 TO 400),y=CLAMP(y,1 TO 400)
7 WAIT SCREEN 
8 GO TO 4
```

Loads the image - colour 15 is bright white, so that becomes transparent.

Using the original image and default SpecBAS palette made it come out a bit odd, so line 2 switches them around to match the input image. Below image shows how it looks without line 2 and after.

[image]

The CLAMP command limits the graphic between 1 and 400 in both directions, saves on several IF...THEN statements.

Line 9 just waits for things to catch up and prevents flickering.

It moves one pixel at a time based on a boolean check of which key is pressed, so takes slightly longer than 5 seconds to go from side to side.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby with Shoes, <s>252</s> 243 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app{background white
i=image'i'
m=[0,0]
a=[:width,:height]
animate(99){i.left+=m[0]<=>i.left
i.top+=m[1]<=>i.top}
keypress{|k|d,v={?u=>[1,-1],?d=>[1,1],?l=>[0,-1],?r=>[0,1]}[k[0]];m[d]=[[m[d]+v*4,self.send(p=a[d])-i.send(p)].min,0].max}}
```

This uses a resizable window starting at default 600 x 500. If you resize the window so the invader is left out, will come back when the next movement key is pressed.

The trick to satisfy the requirements is that invader's position is changed in increments of 4, but the actual movement is made with increment of 1 at 99 frames per second.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua + LÖVE, 291 characters

```lua
x=0
y=0
l=love
g=l.graphics
l.window.setMode(400,400)
i=g.newImage("i")
function l.update()d=l.keyboard.isDown
if d("left")and x>0 then x=x-1 end
if d("right")and x<336 then x=x+1 end
if d("up")and y>0 then y=y-1 end
if d("down")and y<352 then y=y+1 end
end
function l.draw()g.draw(i,x,y)end
```

This uses an unresizable 400 x 400 window. I had no success with adjusting `love.keyboard.setKeyRepeat()` to speed up the key reading, so I did the recommended way, polling each key's status.

As my relation with Lua `for` is not the best, neither this time managed to make looping shorter than the dump hardcoding of each key's condition.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl/Tk](http://tcl.tk/), 242 bytes

```
grid [canvas .c -w 400 -he 403 -bg #FFF -highlightt 0]
.c cr i 30 24 -i [image c photo -fi .png] -t p
lmap {k b x y} "Up 1]>25 0 -5 Right 0]<368 5 0 Down 1]<376 0 5 Left 0]>30 -5 0" {bind . <$k> "if \[lindex \[.c coo p] $b {.c move p $x $y}"}
```

Comment: To run it in any Linux: you must have Tcl and Tk installed; then copy the code to a file, let's say `invaders.tcl`; you need also to have the image saved as `.png` in the same folder. To run the script type `wish invaders.tcl`  in a shell. PS : It can be more golfed if code is instead pasted into an interactive shell, as it supports by default abbreviated commands.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (using paper.js), 215 bytes

```
v=new Raster("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUweU.png",99,99);p=new Size(4,0)
onFrame=e=>{if(!v.isInside(view.bounds)){p=-p};v.position+=p}
onKeyDown=e=>{p=new Size([[0,-4],[0,4],[-4,0],[4,0]]["udlr".indexOf(e.key[0])])}
```

[paper.js](http://paperjs.org) is a JS graphics framework, which means it features many useful features regarding image manipulation. To run, just copy the above into the section on the left [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org), then, to move the alien around, click once in the right section to give it focus. If your browser can handle it, it should run at 60fps.